# Reducing modulo 5 does not make the equations equivalent?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

***Edit 2: I was trying to solve $2^{n} + 5^{n} - 65 = p^{2}$ for positive integer solutions***

$$2^{n} + 5^{n} - 65 \equiv p^{2} \mod 5$$
has different solutions from
$$2^n \equiv p^2 \mod 5$$

Why is this so? Does this mean that both equations are not equivalent? Is reducing modulo $5$ a bad idea for finding integer solutions of $n$ and $p$?

[image]

[image]

Note: There are more solutions (including the solutions for the previous equation) not shown for $2^n \equiv p^2 \mod 5$, but it still stands that there are suddenly more solutions.

Edit: Equation 2 has too many solutions, including solutions where $n$ is not $0$. Here are some of them:
[image]

Comment: $5^n$ is not equal to $0 \mod 5$ if $n=0$. You have to separate the two cases, $n = 0$ and $n \ne 0$

Comment: Ah I should've clarified it better. I obtained too many solutions for the second equation that I couldn't fit in 1 page. I'll edit it in. There are no values of $n$ above 18.

Comment: Wolframalpha decided to make the solutions for the second equation modulo 20, but there are still too many solutions

Comment: I don't understand the $\mod 20$ issue. If $p$ is a solution $\mod 5$, $p+5$ is a solution $\mod 5$ ... You only need to consider $p$ from $0$ to $4$

Comment: @Damien To illustrate, what about the $n \equiv 12, p\equiv 6$ solution? That doesn't reduce to one of the four solutions in the small modulo 5 list.

Comment: But to address the original question, I personally suspect that WolframAlpha simply doesn't understand the problem, and just spits out something it thinks looks nice enough. This happens from time to time. Solve it by hand instead.

Comment: @Arthur Effectively, we can note that $\phi(5) = 4$. Therefore, $2^n \equiv 2^{n \mod 4} \mod 5$

Comment: An example for different solutions: for n=6 we have: $2^6+5^6-65\equiv 65 \bmod 5\equiv 0\bmod 5$, but $2^6\equiv 4 \bmod 5$

Comment: @Damien Yeah, but that's not what WA says. WA gives $n$ modulo 5, not 4.

Comment: @Arthur Here, I have difficulty to understand WA reasoning. My interpretation: what is important is the value of $n \mod 4$. However, we have to make a distinction between $n = 0$ and $n \ne 0$. Therefore, we have to consider $n = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4$

Comment: @sirous $2^6+5^6-65=15624$.

Comment: I think the $n=4,p=1 \pmod{5}$ case is wrong. It should be "$n=0\pmod{4}$ and $p=1 \pmod{5}$". This explains the $12,6$ case. It must be an algorithmic error of the site.

Comment: @helpme, do you want to find a modulus  like k for which $2^n\notequiv 2^n+5^5-65\equiv p^2 \bmod k$?

Comment: I wanted to find integer solutions for $2^{n} + 5^{n} - 65 = p^{2}$ by reducing modulo 5. Unfortunately, doing so somehow created a great number of solutions when the only solution should be $n=4$, $p=24$

Comment: I should've included that in the question whoops

Answer (score 1):

Here, $5^n \equiv 0 \mod 5$, except for $n = 0$.

Therefore, we have to make a distinction between $n = 0$ and $n \ne 0$.

Moreover, $\phi(5) = 4$.

Therefore,

$$ 2^n \mod 5 \equiv 2^{n \mod 4} \mod 5 $$.

As $n = 0$ is a special case, we have to consider $n = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4$.

Concerning $p$: if $p$ is a solution, then $p+5$ is a solution too. Then, for $p$, we have only to consider its value modulo 5.

At this point, it is easy to consider the different cases.

**If $n = 0$:**

$$p^2 = 2 \mod 5$$

It is easy to check that $p^2$ is equal to $0, 1, 4$ modulo 5. So, no solution

**If $n \ne 0$:**

$$p^2 \equiv 2^n \mod 5$$

$$n = 1 \implies p^2=2 \mod 5 \implies no\,solution\,in\,p$$
$$n = 2 \implies p^2=4 \mod 5 \implies p=2\,or\,p=3$$
$$n = 3 \implies p^2=3 \mod 5 \implies no\,solution\,in\,p$$
$$n = 4 \implies p^2=1 \mod 5 \implies p=1\,or\,p=4$$

Comment: Yup, I understand how to obtain solutions from $2^n=p^2$. What concerns me is that reducing modulo $5$ created so many solutions, and separating $n$ into $2$ cases does not seem to resolve this.

Comment: When I provide a solution with $n = 4$, in fact it corresponds to all $n = 4 \lambda$ solutions, with $\lambda \ne 0$. So for example, $n = 8$ is included.